# Data Filter storage?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Just wondered that a Data Filter seems to create a physical Data Extension. Is that Data Filter Extension actually a copy of data that it would take additional storage space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's counts as a new object and takes up its own space. In reality it's an extra data extension

Comment: Ok, so I guess the only other option to filter criteria-based from DE would be through Audiences?

Comment: You are able to send directly to the filter as well, but this means there will be no physical location that the exact data is stored in and you will have no way to know exactly who will receive your email or how many.